# Android элементы уходят за край правой части экрана

Tags: android-layout

помогите пожалуйста, что нужно дописать в xml коде кнопки, что бы она не выезжала за границу экрана 
[image: Это как должно выглядеть]
[image: А это как выглядит оно на самом деле :c]

Comment: Что то странно скрин вставился
1 - это как должно выглядеть
2 - как выглядит на деле

Comment: Покажите xml разметку